# Overloading 'new' and 'delete' operators of a class to return 'new char[]', could it be harmful?

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading, new-operator, delete-operator

I've come across a piece of code that I find suspicious, and I've seen it extensively used in most of the classes of a project.

It's a `new` and `delete` overload like this:

```cpp
void* MyObject::operator new ( size_t  size )
{
    return ( size == 0 ? NULL : new char[size] ) ;
}

void* MyObject::operator new[] ( size_t  size )
{
    return ( size == 0 ? NULL : new char[size] ) ;
}

void MyObject::operator delete( void *p )
{
    char* l_tmp = (char*)p;
    delete[] l_tmp;
}

void MyObject::operator delete[]( void *p )
{
    char* l_tmp = (char*)p;
    delete[] l_tmp;
}
```

Can this be harmful in any way or form regarding memory, speed, or stability?

Does it make any sense?

Comment: it can definitely cause performance issues.  `char`s alignment might not be the same as your type and if you have unaligned memory then you you have a performance cost.  You could also get a crash if your CPU cannot handle unaligned memory access.

Comment: `operator new` is a memory allocation function and is not supposed to create any objects (except possibly for internal bookkeeping), and `operator delete` is a deallocation function that should not destroy anything. Normally, you delegate to `::operator new` and `::operator delete` if you want the memory manager to allocate the memory for you.

Comment: Code looks correct, but the real question is ... why? Perhaps cargo cult programming.

Comment: @NathanOliver The size parameter is given by the compiler based on its alignement, so its aligned in all cases

Comment: @molbdnilo following what you say, it means we are allocating double the needed space for all objects that have that? Could you please cite any source on your statement?

Comment: @Dario-Metalcam No, it does not mean that. The expression `new char[size]` will use the global allocation function `::operator new[]` to allocate memory and create an array of `char` in it, and you're returning a pointer to that memory. See for instance [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new).

Comment: That is, your code is more or less equivalent to `if (size == 0) return nullptr; char* p = ::operator new[](size); return new(p) char[size]; `, where `operator new[]` allocates memory and the placement-new expression creates an array of `char`.

Answer (score 0):

In most standards compliant C++ settings, `new` should throw `std::bad_alloc` rather than return `nullptr`. It's unclear without a lot more context whether changing this behavior for a specific class is actually desirable in your specific instance, or if the code was just written by someone who hates exceptions; however, the fact that the original author wrote `NULL` rather than `nullptr` is circumstantial evidence marking it as "old school" in a way that makes me suspect the latter.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed old school, as the oldest parts with this date back 20 years. Then i think people just went along with it adding that code to any class they created. And indeed, they hated exceptions, all errors are old C style, using int return values and defines for the error codes.

Comment: in that case the main potential harm is that the errors go undetected because someone forgot to check for them and then crash later accessing a null pointer....

Comment: Yeah, all calls to new in the code are followed by a if(ptr != NULL) do stuff, nested to infinity.

Comment: So there are three potential harms here:
(1) there's a vulnerability to crash if someone ever forgets to add one of those `if` statements.
(2) that really clogs up the readability of the code
(3) if the expectation is that the allocation should rarely or never actually return null, there's a performance penalty to not using `try{} catch{}`. The C++ spec requires that a `try{}` which does not throw must have zero runtime cost. An `if` relies on the compiler or processor to be sufficiently smart with branch prediction to optimize the hot path.